# How to redirect specific domains for devices under pc hotspot

Tags: networking, dns, hotspot

I share my internet to my mobile phone using a hotspot from my pc.
is it possible to resolve some domain names for my phone browser in my pc? if yes how is it possible?

for clarification let's say i have connected my phone to my pc using a wifi hotspot, so my android  cell phone is connecting to internet through my pc. can i configure my pc in a way that if i browse for and `www.SomeLocalAddress.com` in my phone so my pc will redirect it to a local address instead of going for it on the internet.

i assume that i don't want to change hosts file of my android phone. i want it to be manageable from my pc if possible.

Comment: Please clarify, “I have connected my phone to my PC using a WiFi hotspot...” how did you do this? How is it configured? How is the PC getting internet access?

Comment: Pc is getting internet from wifi, i got a dual band wifi so one of them is connected to the internet and the other is sharing it on the other frequentcy.